# Default Values in Functions

Tags: python

The following warning is in the Default Values in Function Arguments section in Python Docs.

Important warning: The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes. For example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

This will print

[1]

[1, 2]

[1, 2, 3]

If you don’t want the default to be shared between subsequent calls, you can write the function like this instead:

```
def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

I didn't quite understand how the L=None part of code solves this problem. Can you help me understand. Thanks

Comment: `None` is not mutable but `[]` is.

Comment: Another way to write the `if` can be: `L = L or []`

Answer (score 2):

`None` is immutable, meaning it cannot be changed. So if `None` is set to be the default value of the parameter, it is always the same on every function call, and a new empty list is set to `L` (because it is evaluated every time, not just the first time the function is called).

Further reading: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 1):

Like the documentation mentions, when you put `L=[]` in an argument, the value for the argument is evaluated only one, so the list that `L` has is created only once and shared between invocations.

So, if what you want is to create a new list every time the function is called, you have to create the list inside the function with a statement like `L = []`. But if the caller passes a list, you don't want to create a new empty one, you just want to use the one the caller gave you. That's where the `None` here comes in, it's just a signal that you want an empty list. That's why you do the `if` to check if the argument is `None` and create an empty list only when that's true.

An since `None` is just a value that's immutable, it will not be shared between calls.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about the solution first than we will investigate the problem a little!

```
def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

When you call without passing `L`, a new `list` is being created everytime the function is called. passed value for `a` is appended to `L` and newly created L is returned.

This is pretty straightforward. Let's look at what is happening when L has a default value of `[]`

In Python default values for function parameters are evaluated at the time def is evaluated.

You can see that using `<function_name>.__defaults__`

```
mahorir@mahorir-Vostro-3446:~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)

>>> def fun(a,l=[]):
...     l.append(a);return l
... 
>>> fun.__defaults__
([],)
```

You can see that defaults in the beginning (before calling function is empty list)
After few calls -

```
>>> fun(1)
[1]
>>> fun(2)
[1, 2]
>>> fun(3)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> fun.__defaults__
([1, 2, 3],)
```

This ofcourse surprises every Python developer!